# How can I prevent the truncation of a listview by the layout header?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I cannot see the first row of my listview. I am assuming the screen page's header is overlapping with the listview.

My fragment file is follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="?attr/layout_background_color">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/colors_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/colors_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Any advice tips will be very helpful.

Edit: I am including my activity file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".views.activities.ColorActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/color_fragment"
    android:name="com.microsoft.skype.teams.views.fragments.ColorFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a hack I am currently adding an extra row of data. Adding the extra row of data is clearly something I wish to avoid.

Comment: do you have toolbar added above your listview ?

Comment: If that is indeed a `Fragment`'s layout, the issue is likely in the main, `Activity` layout.

Comment: In your activity layout place the `FrameLayout` below your toolbar.

Comment: This is happening due to the toolbar, Check my answer below and see if you can get what you want.

Comment: The inner elements in that layout suggest that you mean to be using a `<CoordinatorLayout>` as the root, not `<ConstraintLayout>`. If you change to `<CoordinatorLayout>`, the `layout_behavior` on your `<fragment>` will cause it to be laid out below the  `<AppBarLayout>` automagically.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Not sure why but I got a crash (cause Leak Detected). For now, going with Umair's solution. But thanks much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your toolbar is taking the height of your first row. To get out of this do something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="?attr/layout_background_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colors_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"  // added this line now your
        android:orientation="vertical"                     listview will start below
        android:visibility="visible">                      toolbar

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/colors_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)